# SQL Server Delay in Committing Inserted Data

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored proc in SQL Server that is checking for duplicate orders from a mobile device. The device will retry within about 1/2 second if it doesn't get a response from the server. Very occasionally a duplicate will not be read even though it has already been inserted. Is it possible for SQL Server to be delayed 1/2 second in committing inserted data? Is the solution to start using dirty reads?

Comment: Certainly is is very easy for SQL server to get delayed a half second due to other work happening onthe server that may be blocking the insert.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are getting into a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

i.e.

```
Time    SP Call 1        SP Call 2
0.00    Dup Exists?
0.10      ...            Dup Exists?
0.20        No               No
0.30    Insert New         ...
0.40                     Insert New
```

Rather than have a procedure check for duplicates, can you put a unique index on the data to prevent the duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion using dirty reads is never a solution. Uniqueness should be implemented through constraints or in some cases with before(or instead of) triggers. Without details about what procedure does, I cannot give more specific advice, but I believe that the problem may be solved by using serializable isolation level for transaction in the body of stored procedure. Also, you may consider using [rowversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) column to avoid lost update problem.

Comment: a1ex07 and @webturner, thank you for your replies. The difficulty with using a unique constraint is that I am checking for a potential dupicate before submitting a request to another system which will process the order. Therefore, uniqueness of records is not the goal. The goal is to not submit the order to the other system if it has already been sent and confirmed. Therefore, I do need to know if a row exists that would duplicate what I just received in order to make a programmatic decision. That's why I was thinking of read uncomitted in this particular case. Hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: This turned out to be a race condition as @webturner suggested. It was between WCF threads that were accessing the same data in SQL Server. Thanks to a1ex07 as well for valuable information too.